# Writing Logs To Different Folders At Each Day With Log4net

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I want to log different folder at each day with log4net.

What I found so far is  using data pattern with RollingFileAppender:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
 <file value="Logs\logfile.log" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
 <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
 <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd-HHmm" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
<maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
 <countDirection value="1"/>
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
 <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger- %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

But this just create same new file under Logs folder. What  I want is,

**At each different day logger create new folder and write logs under that folder** such as:

> Logs\Day1\logfile.log, Logs\Day2\logfile.log, Logs\N\logfile.log, ...

Is it possible in Log4net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log to directories by add \\:

```
 <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd\\\\`logfile.log" />
 <file value="logs\\" />
```